# Running javascript on page back

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have the following problem:

I've created a form with several input fields like these:

```
<td>Pizza Margherita</td>
<td><input type="number" id="countMargherita" class="formnumbers" name="PizzaMargherita" onChange="validateForm(this);changeTotalFromCount(this);"  data-unitprice="7"/></td>
<td><span id="totalMargherita"></span></td>
```

11 to be exact.

the `onChange="changeTotalFromCount(this)"` looks as follows:

```
function changeTotalFromCount(input) {
        var unitPrice = parseFloat(input.getAttribute("data-unitPrice"));
        var count = input.value;

        var price = unitPrice * count;
        var formattedPrice = '\u20ac ' + price.toFixed(2);

        var label = input.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
        label.innerHTML = '';
        label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(formattedPrice));
    }
```

Now what this does is say the user wants 5 pizza margherita's he enters a 5 in the input field and then immdediately shows the cost which in this case is 7*5= 35. This works just fine, but when the user submits the form he gets taken to another .php file where he sees the confirmation with all the details. There is also a button that needs to take them back to the order page again. I did this first by just sending it straight to my orderform.php but as this doesn't save the customer his input i decided to use this instead:

```
<input type='button' value='Bestelling Wijzigen' onClick="history.go(-1);return false;" class='printbutton'>
```

I don't know if this is the right thing to do or not, but i saves the user's his information as he goes back. Except it doesn't show the prices next to the input anymore unless he/she changes the input again. And there lies my problem, i'd like it so that if the user goes back to change his order he can still see the costs of each product without changing it before he can see it again.

Im not really an expert in JS or PHP.
(if you miss any information please let me know!)

Comment: You would need to store the shopping cart either on the client side using something like localstorage or on the server using for example a session. Then you can build the form correctly every time it is opened.

Comment: You could also look into using historyjs (https://github.com/browserstate/history.js). You will still need to store the state though.

Comment: You can easily store the values in cookies and then retrieve the cookies on the order page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `onload` event to run code that initializes all totals. It's fired when you go to a page with the backbutton as well as when you visit it in any other way.

So, for example

```
function initTotals()
{
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++)
    {
        changeTotalFromCount(inputs[i]);
    }
}

window.onload = initTotals;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XK99Z/

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction, but this doesn't seem to be working for me, i even literally copied your pieces of code but it still won't work. Even though its working perfectly in your jsfiddle

Comment: Do you perhaps use the `window.onload` for something else? Because it might be overwritten. I don't see any other obvious problem where it might interfere with other code, unless something throws an error.

Comment: Wait Nevermind the problem is within the second table on my page, what could cause this? Since the table doesn't do anything on load...

Comment: Of course.....My other table is  part of that form, which of course uses input fields as well, only those are for name, adres, etc.

Comment: If you were using jQuery, Id say just trigger the `change` event on all inputs on `load`, but that's a bit of a bother to do in plain javascript because it's different in different browsers. I suppose you could just check the type attribute to see whether it's a number.